# Creating HTTP post requests with data in python/

Tags: python, http, automation, http-headers, bots

If I wanted to send post request to a website with my username and password data manually via a python function. Is it possible? If so what would some example code be.

Below is some half-assed code as I have no experience with `http requests`:

```
import requests
payload = {"username":"anton","password":"password"}

r = requests.post('https://www.walmart.com/account/login', data = payload)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cleanest way to do HTTP POST with basic auth in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256126/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-do-http-post-with-basic-auth-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
import requests

url = "your_url"
r = requests.post(url, auth=("your_username", "your_password"))

print(r.text)
```

See [requests docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/) for more information.